# How to set same value to multi var under this.setState in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React. I want to set same value for multi var under this.setState How should I write the code?

I tried like following code but not work....

```
isChecked_1 = isChecked_2 = isChecked_3 = isChecked_4 = isChecked_5 = isChecked_6: false,
```

---

//following is my code:

```
export default class StudentForm extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isChecked_1: false,   
      isChecked_2: false,   
      isChecked_3: false,   
      isChecked_4: false,   
      isChecked_5: false,   
      isChecked_6: false,   
    };
  }
  //some code here......
}
```

Comment: under this.state = {...} ? am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
export default class StudentForm extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    for (var i = 1, i <= 6, i++) {
       this.state[`isChecked_${i}`] = false;
    }
  }
  //some code here......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have repeated keys that is a clear indicator that you should use an array instead:

```
  this.state = {
    isChecked: [false, false, false, false, false, false],
  };
```

Or just:

```
  this.state = { isChecked: Array(6).fill(false), };
```

You can then read from it as `this.state.isChecked[5]`, and set isChecked at i:

```
  const i = 5;
  this.setState(({isChecked }) => ({ isChecked: isChecked.map((checked, i2) => checked || i === i2) }));
```

To unset use `&& i !== i2` in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

```
let isChecked_1 = isChecked_2 = isChecked_3 = isChecked_4 = isChecked_5 = isChecked_6 = false
this.state = {
  isChecked_1, 
  isChecked_2,   
  isChecked_3,   
  isChecked_4,   
  isChecked_5,   
  isChecked_6,   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a more **declarative and mutations free** implementation:

```js
const getState = length => {
  // Generate N Items, starting from 1
  const items =  Array.from({ length }, (v, k) => k + 1)
  const state = items.reduce((accumulator, i) => (
    { ...accumulator, [`isChecked_${i}`]: false }), {}
  )

  return state
} 

class StudentForm extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = getState(6);
    
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StudentForm />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```